# Specifying product image upload location for each image

Tags: commerce, files

I have been searching for how to specify the image upload location (folder/directory) for each commerce product, to keep the file system organized. I have been having trouble finding a clear explanation or means. Example: I have a blue shirt, but different kinds under that, and I wish to upload each image/s to different directories under the blue shirt folder. Can anyone please explain, or provide a link, to how I can easily control the upload location for each (product) image?

example.com/files/store/product/shirt/blue/option1/image1.jpg (image2.jpg, image3.jpg...)

example.com/files/store/product/shirt/blue/option2/image1.jpg (image2.jpg, image3.jpg...)

example.com/files/store/product/shirt/blue/option3/image1.jpg (image2.jpg, image3.jpg...)

Thanks!

Comment: I doubt this is possible without custom code. Typically you can use tokens to specify your directory structure, but in the case of attribute options, there's no token that can add a subdirectory based on the theoretical existence of an attribute value on a variation. There's likely a hook you can tap into, though.